# Missing shared libraries when configuring self hosted runner on-demand on AWS EC2

Tags: amazon-web-services, github, github-actions, github-actions-self-hosted-runners

I'm encountering an error while setting up a GitHub Actions self-hosted runner on an AWS EC2 instance. Despite updating the runner version and following the setup steps, I'm facing issues during the configuration phase.

Here's a summary of the steps I followed:

Updated the runner version to the latest one.
Installed necessary dependencies like Docker, Git, jq, and libicu.
Obtained a Personal Access Token (PAT) from GitHub.
Used the PAT to retrieve a registration token for the repository.
Configured the runner with the provided registration token using `./config.sh`.
Attempted to start the runner service with `./svc.sh` start.
However, during the configuration step (`./config.sh`), I encountered the following error:

> ldd: ./bin/libcoreclr.so: No such file or directory
> ldd: ./bin/libSystem.Security.Cryptography.Native.OpenSsl.so: No such file or directory
> ldd: ./bin/libSystem.IO.Compression.Native.so: No such file or directory
> -bash: ./bin/Runner.Listener: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error

Additionally, I noticed that in the latest runner version, there's no `svc.sh` file. Instead, there's a run.sh file. I tried using `./run.sh`, but the error persists.

I've ensured that the necessary permissions are set correctly and that Docker is running. Any insights into resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!